# resizing div issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please open this file in google chrome : http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

It doesn't work properly. When you mouse over the edges, your cursor will change but when you start dragging the cursor changes again, cursor not persistent

how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is the correct answer.

Thanks to [bartaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354604/bartaz) for his helpful and accurate [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745028/chrome-sets-cursor-to-text-while-dragging-why/2943724#2943724).

If you add this in one of your scripts it will fix the issue:

```
    if ($.browser.safari) {
        $.ui.mouse.prototype.__mouseDown = $.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseDown;
        $.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseDown = function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            return $.ui.mouse.prototype.__mouseDown.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
```

Seems Chrome grabs the cursor in its *document.onselectstart* function.

If you would like to test for yourself download the latest version of resizable and place this in \development-bundle\demos\resizable\default.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($.browser.safari) {
        $.ui.mouse.prototype.__mouseDown = $.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseDown;
        $.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseDown = function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            return $.ui.mouse.prototype.__mouseDown.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        $("#resizable").resizable();
    });
</script>
```