# Dragging cursor on SVG element changes cursor to i-beam (e.g. |) on Webkit (Chrome/Safari)

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, svg, cursor, drag

Anywhere inside svg,

- mousedown inside the svg, e.g. on an element or on the svg canvas itself
- drag the cursor around
- note how the cursor changed to an i-beam

Solutions I tried that didn't work

- changing the CSS cursor to the dragged svg element to "cursor: default !important"
- changing the CSS cursor to the root svg element to "cursor: default !important"
- changing the CSS cursor to the html body element to "cursor: default !important"
- using the CSS of all the above 3
- changing document.onselectstart as per [chrome sets cursor to text while dragging, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745028/chrome-sets-cursor-to-text-while-dragging-why)
- changing the root svg element's `cursor` attribute to "default" or "pointer"
- changing the dragged element's `cursor` attribute as above
- changing both the root svg element's and dragged element's `cursor` attribute

I'd appreciate any ideas.  As far as I can tell thus far, it's a bug in Webkit.  This happens in Chrome and Safari but no other browsers.

Answer (score 4):

This is a reported bug in Webkit. It also appears to be fixed in the nightlies, though I'm not sure how to tell when this behaviour will land in Chrome / Safari.

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6002
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17258

See also:

- https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/517

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, or if this is at all a good-enough-for-me (you) fix, but I found that when I call JqueryUI's .draggable on an svg element, the text selector cursor goes away. Probably a bug, but interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SVG source (it's XML), you can add a

```
pointer-events="none"
```

attribute to the <text> element(s). 
This will cause the cursor to remain as the arrow instead of changing to the I-beam.

Not as simple as setting a global CSS attribute, but it is a solution.

Comment: This could work, but it wouldn't be advisable if you need interactivity on the SVG elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
svg { cursor: default; }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: That works today, but not when the webkit bug was active circa 2011.