# Drag and drop cursor changes in safari and chrome while dragging

Tags: jquery, css, html, drag-and-drop

I have set up a drag and drop scenario in the jsFiddle : [Drag N Drop cursors](https://jsfiddle.net/wysgf1ys/31/)

```
<div class="dragMe" draggable="true">Drag Me</div>
<div class="dragHere">Drag Here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dragMe {
  height: 50px;
  width : 50px;
  background-color: Green;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.dragMe:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
.dragHere {
    height: 150px;
    width : 150px;
    background-color: Red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dragMe").on("dragstart", function (event) {
        var dataTransferObj = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dataTransferObj.effectAllowed = "move";
        dataTransferObj.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $(".dragHere").on("dragover drop", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.type === 'dragover') {
            event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
        }
    });
});
```

To start with,  both browsers show the grab cursor that changes to grabbing when active. But in chrome and safari as soon as the drag starts, the cursor changes back to a pointer.

I want to preserve the grabbing hand cursor until drag ends. The images are not great quality but you can see the behavior, I'm talking about.

Firefox behavior:

[image]

Safari & Chrome behavior:

[image]

I have tried changing the cursor css property of the element on the drag events, but that has no effect whatsoever. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `user-select: none` on the .dragHere div

If that doesn't work: [chrome sets cursor to text while dragging, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745028/chrome-sets-cursor-to-text-while-dragging-why)

or: [Safari. Wrong cursor when dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295211/safari-wrong-cursor-when-dragging)