# Safari. Wrong cursor when dragging

Tags: css, safari, drag-and-drop, cross-browser, cursor

I'm trying to add drag-and-drop functionality to my project and using [slip.js](https://github.com/pornel/slip) for this.

To decorate cursor I've add `class="draggable"` to each draggable `<tr>`. The CSS for this class is:

```
.draggable:active { 
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor:    -moz-grabbing;
  cursor:         grabbing;
}
```

Drag-and-drop works fine, but in Safari when I'm dragging a table row the cursor looks like `cursor: text`[image: text cursor]

In Chrome the cursor is OK [image: grabbing cursor]

Interesting that when I just click and hold without dragging the cursor is OK in Safari too [image: grabbing cursor]

Comment: The code seems right, difficult to help without being able to test.

Comment: @LesserEvil, looks like you are right. But my problem happens in Safari but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [chrome sets cursor to text while dragging, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745028/chrome-sets-cursor-to-text-while-dragging-why), I need to disable selection when dragging. My JavaScript for this:

```
list = document.getElementById('demo1');

var flag_dragging = false;
list.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  document.onselectstart = function(){ return false; }
});

list.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
  if(!flag_dragging){
    document.onselectstart = function(){ return true; }
  }
});

list.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
  flag_dragging = true;
});

list.addEventListener('dragstop', function(e){
  flag_dragging = false;
});
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me - and I read many.

Comment: super - setting 'document.onselectstart' fixes the Safari issue